# Issue reading input data from 2D array

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a matrix algebra program, so I began with a pre defined 3x3 matrix. Ran into some issues with the elements not being read properly into the 2D array so I isolated one . The issue is that the last number in a row is printed as the first element in the next row. i.e. array[1][2] is printed out as what array [2][0] is.

Again, if I have a 3x3 matrix where we go from 1 to 9, and I want the value at row 1 column 3 (which is 3), it'll give me 4. Same goes for row 2 column 3; the value is 6 but it gives me 7.

I've put in a print statement to show me the counter values before input and they're correct. Something is going on with the scanf I guess but I'm really stumped. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int matrix1[2][2];

void main(void)
{
    int i = 0, j=0;    //Row and column subscripts for the first matrix 

    //======================================================================================================//
    //First Matrix
    printf("This is for the first matrix");
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) //Start with row
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("\nInsert the value at row %d, column %d: ", i+1,j+1); //+1 since array's begin at 0
            printf("\ni is %d, j is %d", i,j); //Shows what elements the input will go into
            scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]); //Enter value into row i column j
        }

    }
    printf("\n\n%d", matrix1[1][2]); //test to see what's in the element
}
```

Comment: first ,`int matrix1[2][2];` --> `int matrix1[3][3];`

Comment: That would give me a 4x4 wouldn't it?

Comment: `int matrix1[3][3];` give 3x3. matrix1[0..2][0..2]. try test `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(matrix1)/sizeof(int));`

Comment: No. In C, array indices for arrays of size n run from 0 to n - 1. If you want a 3 x 3 matrix, you need to define `int matrix[3][3]` which will have indices from 0 to 2 in each dimension.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks everyone! It works now. I'm guessing that I the last element is for the null zero? Just getting my feet wet in C, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 3

int matrix1[ROWS][COLS];

void main(void)
   {
   int i, j;    //Row and column subscripts for the first matrix 

   //================================================================================
   //First Matrix
   printf("This is for the first matrix");
   for(i=0; i < ROWS; i++) //Start with row
      {
      for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
         {
         printf("\nInsert the value at row %d, column %d: ", i+1,j+1); 
         printf("\ni is %d, j is %d", i,j); 
         scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
         }
      }

   printf("\n\n%d", matrix1[1][2]); //test to see what's in the element
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You are confused with **array index numbers** and **total number of elements** in array.

For Example When You have array of 5 integers.

```
   int ary[5] = {11,22,33,44,55};

 `------------IN Memory-----------
  | 11 || 22 || 33 | | 44 | | 55 |      
   -------------------------------  `
    0     1     2       3      4  <--------These are called Index numbers.
                                           They always start with 0,Hence 
                               they always end with(Total Number of elements - 1)
```

Hence From above explanation you either want to change the size of array

from `int matrix[2][2]` to `int matrix[3][3];`

**OR**

either change your `for()` loops to

```
 for(i=0; i < 2; i++) //changed i<3 to i<2 
 {
     for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) //changed i<3 to i<2
    {
      // your Code.....  
    }
}
```